# A batch file for shutdown with prompt option to abort it and re-run after a certain time of amount?

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file

I have a batch file to shutdown the PC

> @echo off
>   Shutdown /s /f /t 600 /c "Your system will shutdown in 10 min"

To abort this operation I've another one

> shutdown /a

Now what I'm looking for is there any way that when I launch the first batch file it should prompt me to abort the operation or not. If I abort the operation it should be prompt me after  10 min the same option and I want it in loop until I don't accept the operation to done.

I've Googled for it but got nothing so far. Only got some 3rd party tools to do shutdown without abort option.

Is it possible? If yes any help would be appreciated.

Comment: use `set /p varname=` to prompt for input, then test that var's value.

Comment: @MarcB can you elaborate it through an answer if you can.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did this in a single batch file. If you want it to run every 10 minutes don't want the window to stay there for those 10 minutes timegap, then remove the 'timeout and goto' and run it using the Windows Task Scheduler

```
@ECHO OFF
:myLabel
SHUTDOWN /S /F /T 600
SET /P continue="Your computer is about to shutdown in 10 min do you want to abort (y/n): "
IF %continue% EQU y (
SHUTDOWN /A
TIMEOUT /T 600 /NOBREAK
GOTO myLabel
)
```

Comment: Just command line window stays on the screen there is no option to give the input of y/n. Also there should be message to user that `Your computer is about to shutdown in 10 min do you want to abort (y/n):`

Comment: Did the necessary changes, please check it now.

Comment: no it doesn't prompt still now,  just a blank command line windows with blinking cursor.

Comment: @Chirag: Excuse me, but there is not a _practical_ way to execute a program every 10 minutes using the Task Scheduler (AT command). Perhaps you know a trick to do that...

Comment: @Aacini There is. Am not sure how its done using the AT command, but using the GUI of Task Scheduler, this can be achieved.
Check [this image](http://www.connectedaction.net/wp-content/uploads/2010/08/2010-NodeXL-Data-Collector-Task-Scheduler-New-Task-New-Trigger.png).
In that, we can select the 2nd checkbox (Repeat task every 10 minutes).

Comment: @avirk Thats weird, it worked perfectly on my system. What version of Windows are you using? And did you try running it as an Administrator?

Comment: @Chirag: How the GUI of Task Scheduler can be accessed from a Batch file? Remember that _that_ is the core point of the current question...

Comment: I thought it wouldn't be a problem since that is to be done only once. Eitherways, its not necessary as long as the user doesn't mind having the file run as minimized at all the times. But if he wants the wait time to be run in the background, only then Task Scheduler comes into the picture. :)

Comment: @Chirag: You assumed the OP wants the shutdown be active at all times, as soon as the system startup. I think he wants a Batch file he may start at the moment he wishes. Note that, in order to prompt the user for the next Y/N confirmation, the file can not run minimized nor in the background. Anyway, these all are just suppositions; we need confirmation from the OP...

Comment: @Chirag Ah! I was missing it `run as admin` I had check it and its working thanks.

Comment: @Chirag I'll give you the bounty tomorrow, but I need a little bit more favor if you can do it. I want if I closed the command line windows then the batch file should be rerun after the amount of time is it possible. However I'll give you the bounty in any way.

Comment: You can try a batch to exe converter, that will enable you to run the process in the background, though that would kind of defeat the purpose of a batch file in the first place...

Comment: Monitoring if the batch file has been closed or not can be done only if the monitoring process itself is running, which will also be minimized if its a batch file. You may have to use an if condition with a combination of tasklist in the other batch file, but it will be a very tedious and unsure way of checking it.